# why the function has to be measurable with respect to a countably generated $\sigma$-field?

Tags: measure-theory

**Suppose $A$ is a collection of subsets of the nonempty set $\Omega$. Let $\mathcal{A}=\sigma(A)$, that is the $\sigma$-field generated by $A$. Now let $f:\Omega\rightarrow(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$ be a unction which is measurable with respect to $\mathcal{A}$. Then we need to prove that there exists a countable subset of $A$, say $A_f$, such that $f$ is also measurable with respect to $\sigma(A_f)$.**

I have solved a **similar problem** which said: $\{f_{\alpha}:\alpha\in\Lambda\}$ is collection of function from $%\Omega$ to $(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$. Then a function $g:\Omega\rightarrow(\mathbb{R},\mathcal{B})$ is measurable with respect to the $\sigma$-field generated by $\{f_{\alpha},\alpha\in\Lambda\}$, if and only if it is measurable with respect to the $\sigma$-field generated by a countable subcollection of $\{f_{\alpha}:\alpha\in\Lambda\}$.

I solved this second problem using the fact that: (**Hint**) If $\mathcal{H}$ is a collection of functions on $(\Omega,\mathcal{A})$ containing the constant function 1, closed under linear combination, monotone limits and containing the indicator functions $\textbf{1}_{B}$, for all $B$ belonging to some semifield generating $\mathcal{A}$, then $\mathcal{H}$ contains all the measurable functions.

The two problems seem so similar but I can't solve the first one. Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $\mathcal A_f:=\{f^{-1}(a,b),a,b\in\mathbb Q\}$. This forms a countable collection contained in $\mathcal A$ ($f$ is measurable).